# Updating a Twilio "send message" message-body in a Flow using REST API

Tags: twilio

I have dynamically changing data that I would like to push to the message body replies in my Flows for the most up to date info for users.

Send Message Widget Doc is here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/send-message

Thus I'm looking for help on what the proper API format is to POST / PUT (using curl) to the Twilio API to update a **Message Body** in this widget of a Flow.

For example if I have a "Send Message" widget and its name is send_message_1, what would the format be for the API?

*(I know I can add a http GET to my Flow to fetch dynamic data, but this is not an option in my work environment at this time.  So I'm looking to manually POST the data.)*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot POST data to an active Twilio Studio flow. You will need to bring in content via the HTTP Request Widget or Run Function widget and then use liquid syntax for the body of the Send Message widget to represent this dynamic content.

Alan

Comment: Thanks I have confirmed this as well with Twilio support.  Apparently it is in the works for being developed.

Comment: Is this developed ?